# CSS animation Bug in Firefox

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a CSS animation on a Website to make a hover effect on a button.

In Chrome and IE it lokes fine but in Firefox I got a ugly issue.

[image]

some White pieces still standing after hover.

Animation CSS:

```
.Hotel:hover{
   animation-name: pulse;
   animation-duration: 1s;
 }


@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(100.10, 10.10, 10.10);
    transform: scale3d(100.10, 10.10, 10.10);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.80, 1.80, 1.80);
    transform: scale3d(1.80, 1.80, 1.80);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just tested this on Firefox and Firefox Dev-Edition on Mac and it looks fine. Does this happen on windows? And if so, what is your version of firefox?

Comment: firefox 46 ubuntu, looks fine too.

Comment: yes on windows FF: 45.0.2

Comment: That some hardware acccleration issue due to rendering

Comment: Firefox 32.0 looking fine, running on Windows 8 over Parallels

Comment: Have you tried activating `Options > General > Browsing > Use hardware acceleration when available`? It gave me real headaches in the past drawing fonts and borders

Comment: Will you please add the relevant code directly to your question? Now, the link that used to point to the live demo links to an empty directory listing, so your question is norepro… Also, do I get correctly that the bug is that the two white triangles under Galerie should not be there?

Comment: @Palec Problem already solved you can see in the answer right under this question!

Comment: I know, @Felix. But this site is about building a repository of useful questions and answers, not about helping individuals. People may come here months later from search results... Your question is much less useful now, since the original code is unavailable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything Looks fine it might be due to hardware acceleration settings not be on

Use hardware acceleration when available turned on .

> Currently, browsers like Chrome, FireFox, Safari, IE9+ and the latest
>   version of Opera all ship with hardware acceleration; they only use it
>   when they have an indication that a DOM element would benefit from it.
>   With CSS, the strongest indication is that a 3D transformation is
>   being applied to an element.Since you have already that done your 
>   then other than hardware acceleration turned on nothing seems to cause problem
>   its fine in my browser.

In Chrome and Safari we might see a flickering effect when using CSS transforms or animations. The following declarations can be used to fix the issue:

```
.className{
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;

   backface-visibility: hidden;

   -webkit-perspective: 1000;
   -moz-perspective: 1000;
   perspective: 1000;
   /* Other transform properties here */
}
```

Another method that seems to work well in WebKit-powered desktop and mobile browsers is translate3d:

```
.className{
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  /* Other transform properties here */
}
```

Native mobile applications also make good use of the device GPU –– that’s why they’re known to perform slightly better than Web apps. Using hardware acceleration can be especially useful on mobile devices because it helps reduce resource consumption on the device.

Comment: which css class should get those options?

Comment: Felix add these inside hover class and what is your browser version and have you turned on the hardware acceleration setting.and append it hover class content after animation duration

Comment: hardware acceleration works fine. 

the first options added to the :hovers - So it looks fine FireFox but not working in IE 11 now ..

Comment: remove the `-ms-transform:`, `-ms-perspective:`, `-ms-backface-visibility`  css properties, they're only applying to IE

Comment: done, but animation not working anymore in IE ... link to website is in my first post there you can see it

Comment: @Felix was it doing the same issue in IE before ?If else as pascual told remove ms properties he is right from and from IE 10 onwards vendor specific -ms- is not needed as explained in documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772262(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes -ms- stuff is removed ... It worked fine bevore I added the options you sad

Comment: Added a screenshot from IE above

Comment: Bro please update code in website for time being so that I can view it from here in actual situation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111775/discussion-between-felix-and-sachin-divakar).